# Angular ng-repeat and jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to turn [this jQuery plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/ExxaU/)  into an Angular directive. I did the following:

```
define(['directives/directives'], function(directives){
directives.directive('vivifysortable', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope){
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs){
            // here i pasted definition of multiselectable, 
            //and multisortable from the above jsfiddle
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if ($scope.$last === true) {                    
                setTimeout(function() {
                        angular.element($element).multisortable({                            
                        connectWith: ".product-backlog-column",
                        selectedClass: "ui-selected"
                    });
                })
            }
         }   
    }
}]); 
});
```

And this works fine if I have something like this

```
 <ul class="product-backlog-column" vivifysortable >
    // some hardcoded values for testing purposes
    <li> test  1 </li>
    <li> test  2 </li>
    <li> test  3 </li>
 </ul>
```

But in case I use `ng-repeat` , looks like it doesn't work at all

```
<ul class="product-backlog-column" vivifysortable >
    <li ng-repeat='item in items'>
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

It looks like, ng-repeat` is giving me hard times, but I'm not sure why, and how I can fix it.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqARD/34/) for this (I'm not sure if I created it properly, by including Angular onLoad and jQuery as external resources).

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with the same code?

Comment: I just added jsfiddle, please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `$timeout`. Refactored code looks like this:

```
 link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                angular.element($element).multisortable({

                    connectWith: ".product-backlog-column",
                    selectedClass: "ui-selected"
                });
            }, 0);

  }
```

The thing is that `$timeout` will stop executing of directive, until `ng-repeat` is finished with rendering. That's my beginner's explanation. If someone more experienced can put more light on this, please do.